# Finitely generated subgroups of $\mathrm{Gal}(\bar{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, field-theory, galois-theory

The category of groups is complete and co-complete and any group is the co-limit of its finitely generated subgroups. This means that knowing finitely generated subgroups of $\mathrm{Gal}(\bar{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})$ is equivalent to knowing $\mathrm{Gal}(\bar{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})$ itself. But I don't even know where to start with this, or how these finitely generated subgroups are even categorized (if they are). Any help with how I should tackle this problem and where to start is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're hoping for. The cyclic subgroups are finitely generated, and sufficiently precise knowledge of them would require knowing all elements of $\mathrm{Gal}(\bar{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})$.

Comment: I mean $\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb Q}/\mathbb Q) = \varprojlim_K\mathrm{Gal}(K/\mathbb Q)$ is also the limit of its finite quotients, which seems to me to be far more natural! Of course, that just tells you how complex $\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb Q}/\mathbb Q)$ really is.

Comment: @JoshuaP.Swanson I don't even know precisely what I'm looking for, I was just looking for guidance. Ah, I see, so to know the group you should know about all of the cyclic subgroups which requires knowing all the elements. (So this approach of identifying the subgroups wouldn't help anyway.)

Comment: @Mathmo123 That's something I'm not really familiar with, but I will look into it! Thank you!

Comment: @Zara As for "guidance", I am by no means a number theorist, so take this with a grain of salt. But I'd suggest starting with some fear (alternatively, respect) for $\mathrm{Gal}(\bar{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})$. It seems to be too large for humans to comprehend beyond some shadows it throws.